# update the codebehind on already published wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, updates

I have a WPF application that I have published a year ago and had been using it(and MSSQL database .mdf-extension) that I filled by the past year with some data.

Now I have made some changes in the code behind (filename.cs) in my application so when I publish I get a fresh new database. And I want to use the already filled database.

How do I accomplish that(This comes like an upgrade/update to my WPF app)?

Comment: how is the database set up in your project? it sounds like the application is _meant_ to create / recreate the database.

Comment: what have you changed that is causing the update to use a new Database..? you need to provide more detailed information in regards to what you have changed, what is different about the updated .cs file that was different from the working old release, where is the code sample that you are using..?

Comment: I have made some new things in the code let say if a number was presented with dots 11.11.11. now in the cs i have changed to be presented with , 11,11,11, when i publish it creates new database and i want to use the old one from the previous publish which is already filled with records

Comment: If you are working with Entity Framework as ORM there is a new utility called "Migrations", I don't know if it will fit in your app, but it does exactly what you are asking. There is a ton of info in the official Entity Framework site.

Comment: Did the database schema/structure change, or is it just the format of the data that is saved to the database that has changed?  If the database has changed, then you will need the new one and migrate the old data over.  If it's just the data, then you can devise a scheme to do a data conversion in the existing database.  Please provide more details on your scenario.

Comment: the structure is the same, i just need to know how to get the data from the old version to the new version./..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an SQL Schema Compare tool to compare your old SQL Schema and new SQL Schema. There are various tools, in fact Visual Studio even has one.

But for complex scenarios you may have free alternatives

All you need is to define schema changes between your databases, and edit the generated diff SQL in order to preserve the data.